# passing selector as variable in a function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, selector

trying to pass a selector as a variable doesn't seem to work. I can get this to work outside of a function, so not sure what is happening.

```
function doTheHarlemShake() {
    var shakeItem = $(".letsGetStarted");
    if( shakeItem.hasClass("show") ) {
        alert("works")
        shakeItem.delay(2000).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 800);
        shakeItem.delay(2000).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 800);
        shakeItem.delay(2000).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 800);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do, how are you going to use it?

Comment: I can't see how this wouldn't work. Could you show it in (non-)action?

Comment: could it be that it must be in a $(document).ready(function(){});

Comment: It may be fact that inside function "this" means - this function, not this element that was defined above function. But hard to tell only from what you've pasted.

Comment: ideally I would be passing a selector into the function. but for now I am just testing it in a simple way. here is ideally how I would like to use it http://jsfiddle.net/gFE9f/

Comment: @Hello-World is is already inside document read function

Comment: It work when you link proper librairies : http://jsfiddle.net/gFE9f/1/

Comment: works perfectly after you included the libraries correctly...http://jsfiddle.net/gFE9f/4/ @karl beat me to it;)

Comment: doh. you are right. it ended up being combination of things. thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **exact** code works that you provided in the Fiddle, all I did in my Fiddle was include the jQuery and jQueryUI references:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gFE9f/3/)

```
var shakeMe = $(".letsGetStarted");
doTheHarlemShake(shakeMe);

function doTheHarlemShake(shakeItem) {
    if( shakeItem.hasClass("show") ) {
        shakeItem.delay(2000).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 800);
        shakeItem.delay(2000).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 800);
        shakeItem.delay(2000).effect("bounce", { times: 3 }, 800);
    }
}
```

Comment: the web-console (F12) is your friend. `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` (Could have told the OP something is wrong.) Perhaps you should explain something about the actual error instead of just repeating the OPs code.

Comment: it was actually some other code I had, using console more I determined that the element was getting the show class applied and started with a hide class. but when I viewed the code it had show class, this is where I was getting tripped up. It must apply the show class very fast.